# Can see the code in dreamweaver design view but not in browser

Tags: php, css, dreamweaver

I have 3 files created in dreamweaver 1)mainfile.php 2)sidecolumn.php 3) style.css. Now I linked the css file with main file and called the sidecolumn file with the code

```
<?php include('sidecolumn.php');?>
```

I'm able to see the sidecolumn in the main file (in design view of dreamweaver) but the problem is when i tried to run in the browser, it is completely blank.

This is the code for mainfile.php

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="right">  <!----this the wrapper in stylesheet---->
<?php include('sidecolumn1.php');?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code of sidecolumn1.php

```
<div class="sidecolumn">
<div class="box_1b  box_x">
<div class="name_1 round_corner_top">Video categories:</a></div>
<ul class="list_2">
<li><a href="/site1/" title="Site1">Site1</a></li>
<li><a href="/site2/" title="Site2">Site2</a></li>
<li><a href="/site3/" title="Site3">Site3</a></li>
</ul><!--/list_1-->
<div class="slideDown">More [+]</div>
</div><!--/box_1b-->

<div class="box_1b  box_x">
<div class="name_1 round_corner_top">Video categories:</a></div>
<ul class="list_2">
<li><a href="/site4/" title="Site4">Site4</a></li>
<li><a href="/site5/" title="Site5">Site5</a></li>
<li><a href="/site6/" title="Site6">Site6</a></li>
</ul><!--/list_1-->
<div class="slideDown">More [+]</div>
</div><!--/box_1b-->
</div>
```

Comment: What URL is displayed in the address bar of the browser?

Comment: I'm testing with on my local pc. the url is d:\mydocuments\mysite\main.php

Comment: What is the output HTML?

Comment: Is `sidecolumn.php` in the same directory as `mainfile.php`? If not that would be a start.

Without seeing your code, a live example or an in depth explanation, people are going to struggle to help you.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I didn't get it....you mean the result??

Comment: @user3106380 — He means "When you view > source in your browser, what does it show?"

Answer (score 0):

> I'm testing with on my local pc. the url is `d:\mydocuments\mysite\main.php`

PHP is (in this context) a *server side* programming language.

It must be interpreted by a web server (which needs to support PHP).

You can't load the file *directly* into your browser from your file system.

You must set up a web server and access it via an `http://` (or `https://`) URI.

Comment: yea but rest things are  working fine...the css is well connected. There is also One javascript for menu (not mentioned in the code). even it is called from jscript. I have also linked few images and ads code they all are visible then why only this part is not working.

Comment: Because everything else is *client side* code. PHP is not client side code so it needs a server.

Comment: well then i got another problem. I already have one site running and actually I'm upgrading this with new pages. How can I test it? Mine is apache server with phpadmin loaded. if i load these files on server how should i run it? I mean what will be the url? I tried directly running from cpanel but it showed only code not the browser file. can you pls advice..